# How can I validate specific field/property of specific model instance in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a model class with 4 properties:

```
public class ModelClass
    {
        [Required]
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

        [MinLength(5)]
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }

        [MinLength(5)]
        public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    }
```

View, where I enter only prop2:

```
@model ModelClass
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop2)
```

And some controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ModelClass postedModel)
        {
            var originalModel = Session["model"] as ModelClass;
            return View();
        }
```

**The thing is:** entire model is stored in `Session`, because it is filled on separated views. What I need is to validate only `Prop1` of the model, which was stored in `Session`. If validation fails I need to redirect to some other `View1` if `Prop1` is invlaid or `View3` if `Prop3` is invalid etc. In controller I have posted model with only `Prop2` and model from `Session`. I can't use `ModelState` and it's methods such as `ModelState.IsValidField()` for example because it will be the validation info of posted model. Also I can't use `controller.TryValidateModel(originalModel)` because I just get `false` and I'll get no info about why it is `false`, so I will not be able to redirect to `View1` if `Prop1` is invalid or to `View3` if `Prop3` is invalid. **So how can I validate only Prop1 of originalModel?**

Answer (score 1):

Use view models:

```
public class Step1ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

and then make your view strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model Step1ViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop1)
```

and finally have your HttpPost controller action take the view model as action argument so that you could successfully validate it only in the context of the current wizard step:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Step1ViewModel postedModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // validation for this step failed => redisplay the view so that the 
        // user can fix his errors
        return View(postedModel);
    }

    // validation passed => fetch the model from the session and update the corresponding
    // property
    var originalModel = Session["model"] as ModelClass;
    originalModel.Prop1 = postedModel.Prop1;

    return RedirectToAction("Step2");
}
```